# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...-env":"^7.4.4","@babe'

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader

I got this error while creating my first react app using : `npx create-react-app my-app` .

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...-env":"^7.4.4","@babe'

Answer (score 4):

`npm cache clean --force` fixed the issue.